# How do I concatenate Parameter value to string in JasperReports MongoDB Query?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, parameter-passing

We are creating topics in *JasperReports Server* which are basically blank reports creating in *iReport* or *Jaspersoft Studio* by specifying a query in the form:

```
{
collectionName: "collectionName"
}
```

My problem is that my collections are stored in the format 
`abc.xyz.<ID>` Where the `ID` field determines the ID of the collection.

So my query should be parameterized and should look like:

```
{
collectionName: "abc.xyz." + $P{ID}
}
```

Where `$P{ID}` is a parameter passed to the report.

Now the problem is that Jasper does not evaluate the concatenation, even if I have given a default value to it. So my query ends up looking like

```
{
collectionName: "abc.xyz." + "idtwo"
}
```

Whereas I expect it to look like

```
{
collectionName: "abc.xyz.idtwo"
}
```

Causing *JR Server* to report an error to me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: exception getting dataset from cache

Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: { collectionName: "abc.xyz." + "idtwo" }
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable and use it as the value for collection name as following.

```
{
    collectionName : $V{myCollectionNameParam}
}
```

Then in your report design; define above used variable value as following.

```
"abc.xyz." + $P{ID}
```

Comment: I have tried the same, it doesn't work. I get the same error, 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: exception getting dataset from cache

Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: { collectionName: $V{myCollectionNameParam} }
}`